# Firebase app crash while uploading image

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

My app needs to upload image to firebase storage and display it in a recyclerView. My first two images displays well on the list. But, as I try to upload the third image, the app crashes and also can't store the image on firebase. Each image size varies from 500KB to 700KB. I also have used android:largeHeap="true" in my manifest. What to do?

//Here's the code:

```
public class PostActivity extends Activity {


private EditText postTitle;
private EditText postDescription;
private Button submitButton;
private Uri imageUri=null;
private StorageReference storage;
private ProgressDialog progressDialogue;
private DatabaseReference database;
public  String titleVal;
public String descriptionVal;
private ImageView mImageView;
private static final int GALLERY_REQUEST=1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    storage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");





    mImageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    postTitle=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleField);
    postDescription=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.descriptionField);
    submitButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.submitPost);
    progressDialogue=new ProgressDialog(this);


    imageUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri"));
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    img.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

//What happens after post is SUBMITED.

```
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startPosting();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("titleVal", titleVal);
    outState.putString("descriptionVal",descriptionVal );

}


private void startPosting() {


    titleVal=postTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    descriptionVal=postDescription.getText().toString().trim();



    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(titleVal) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(descriptionVal) && imageUri!=null){
        progressDialogue.setMessage("আপলোড হচ্ছে......");
        progressDialogue.show();

        StorageReference filePath=storage.child("post_images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        filePath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri downloadUrl=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                Picasso.with(PostActivity.this).load(downloadUrl).into(mImageView);
                DatabaseReference newPost=database.push();
                newPost.child("title").setValue(titleVal);
                newPost.child("description").setValue(descriptionVal);
                newPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());





                progressDialogue.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide a Title", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    }

}
```

Comment: What is your error log saying ?

Comment: How your storing the image in firebase ? ex:Base64 string or built in file upload method

Comment: I am using string. I should have pasted the code here too. Didn't I ? Is it ok to paste it now?

Comment: @ShoummoRauth Yes, please edit your post to include Code Snippets for more context.

Comment: add your Error for get more idea

Answer (score 2):

try below code, I am using this code to upload image to firebase storage and let me know if you find any issue or have any queries

[image: Uploading image to firebase storage]
[image: After uploading image to firebase storage]

**See below image , you can see image has been uploaded successfully**
[image: Firebase storage image]

**1 - In your Java file, put these code**

```
private SimpleDraweeView imgProfile;
private FirebaseStorage storage;
private Uri file, resultUri;
private StorageMetadata metadata;
private UploadTask uploadTask;
private StorageReference storageRef;
private final String MY_BUCKET_PATH = "YOUR BUCKET PATH OF YOUR STORAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl(MY_BUCKET_PATH);
}
```

**2 - After getting Uri of your image in onActivityResult upload image to firebase storage, also make sure you are getting proper image Uri**

```
private void UploadImage() {

    file = Uri.fromFile(new File(resultUri.getPath()));

    // Create the file metadata
    metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder().setContentType("image/jpg").build();

    // Upload file and metadata to the path 'images/mountains.jpg'
    uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/" + file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            showUploadProgress(progress);
            System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        }
    }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("Upload is paused");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Log.e("Uploading image==", "onSuccess");
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
            imgProfile.setImageURI(Uri.parse(downloadUrl.toString())); // Here image will be reflected after uploading
            mDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("DownloadUrl getPath==>>", taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().getPath());
            Log.e("Metadata getPath==>>", taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getPath());  // this line will give you path to download Image from Firebase storage omitting child storage reference
            Log.e("Metadata dwndUrl getpath", taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl().getPath());
            Log.e("storageRef path==>>", taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getPath());
            mSessionManager.storeStringValues("profile_photo", downloadUrl.toString());
            mSessionManager.storeStringValues("profile_photo_path", taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getPath());
        }
    });
}
```